# How can I convert a decimal builtin function call to a decimal variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i1 is a decimal variable. In this code, the second line produces an error because x is a builtin function type rather than a variable. How do I convert x to a decimal variable?

```
x = i1.sqrt
x = x / 2
```

Comment: Did you mean to use i1.sqrt()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to cal the `sqrt()` method:

```
x = i1.sqrt()
```

Comment: Nice copy of my comment :P